# Why defining body attributes in css?

Tags: css

I have seen some web design lessons that always start with a css like this:

```
body,html {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

I'm trying to figure out what's the point of declaring attributes like `width`, `height` or `display` for `body` and `html` that are, if I'm not wrong, by default in browsers.

I thought it would be to prevent and undefined return or similar when accessing the css with js, but the result is the same when the attributes are defined in the css than when left to default:

```
console.log($("BODY").css('width')); // Always returns the width of the body
```

I also thought it could be to start the inheritance in cascade elements, but a `div` inside the `body` inherits the value just the same.

Anybody knows a solid reason for this approach? any browser / device issue I have missed? future compatibility? plain pedantry?

I'm kind of curious about it.

Comment: None of those properties are inherited. Other than the margin, width and height values not being the default for body (and width/height for html), yeah I don't really see why the display and padding declarations are there.

Comment: It's meant to reset default `margin`/`padding` values used by browsers - they might differ between browsers and setting them to 0 makes for a common and unified baseline for other styles. Check http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/ for an example of a more complicated *reset* definition.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: The display, width, height and padding declarations are not necessary. If all you want to do is remove the default body margins, body { margin: 0; } is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks @MarcinJuraszek but whay I trying to find is display, width and height. Why set the values to block and 100% when those are default values and why would anybody want to set different values to the body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good reason to define the html and body width and height to 100%. Say you want to vertically align a relative positioned div, you need to put it into an absolute positioned container:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#main {
  background: lightgrey;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="main">
    <h1>MY DIV</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

But, setting the body width and height to 100% you get an absolute positioned container that covers the whole window:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#main {
  background: lightgrey;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <h1>MY DIV</h1>
</div>
```

You get the same result, but it saves you a div element.